# Symfony - CSRF field on login page is empty after session times out and unrelated form is submitted

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with the sfGuardPlugin. If my session times out while I'm sitting on a page within the app, and I try to submit a form that is on that page, I will get redirected to the login page (this is good, because my session has timed out). But it thinks the login form has already been submitted, and that I've failed validation -- username, password, and CSRF are all missing and required.

Why does it think I've already submitted the login form, and why is the CSRF empty?

Now as a user I would be totally stuck, because I'm on the login page and the hidden CSRF field is empty. Even if I fill in the username and password, I can never pass validation because the CSRF is required.

I'm not really sure where to look. My sfGuardPlugin configuration is fairly standard, I think. The login page and the CSRF protection generally works fine.

The action I'm using just does
`$this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()),       $request->getFiles($this->form->getName()));`

Comment: Have you considered using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin instead?

Comment: No, because we're using Propel.

Answer (score 1):

there're some mistake you may make

1. processing the form both by get and post. add if($request->isMethod('post')) to handle form submit only by post.
2. didn't render the hidden field in the template. csrf field is hidden. using 
   echo $form to render the entire form or $form->renderHiddenFields()

Comment: Thanks for the checks. For #1, which form do you mean? For the login page, I haven't touched the sfGuardPlugin code so I assume that it's not a problem. For my own action, I have a separate action that processes the form, so there's no way to hit the action without doing a post.

Comment: For #2, I'm definitely outputting the csrf field as I am using $form->renderHiddenFields() in both forms. But sometimes that csrf field has an empty value, which is what I can't figure out.